# documentation of spring security in single html

Tags: spring-security

Is it possible to get a "single html" version of spring security documentation? Currently when I open the website https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/index.html every chapter has its own website and it's difficult to find something with CTRL+F. I've found that the docs is generated by tool Antora but I have no idea how to use it.

I was trying to google it but I found no useful tips.

Comment: Have you tried using the search provided by the documentation (can be activated using ctrl+k)?